# Setup Google datastore on local machine issue

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore

I am completely new to Google datastore and I am trying to get it to run on my local development machine, but I am having some issues. I have been following this link to set it up: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/devserver

1) Downloaded gcd tool. Extracted it and created/started the local dev server which succeeded:

```
 gcd-v1beta2-rev1-3.0.2/gcd.sh create ~/Desktop/mygoogletestapp
 gcd-v1beta2-rev1-3.0.2/gcd.sh start --testing ~/Desktop/mygoogletestapp
```

I then set two environment variables:

```
export DATASTORE_HOST=http://localhost:8080
export DATASTORE_DATASET=mygoogletestapp
```

I then doubled checked the variables were set with by echoing them:

```
echo $DATASTORE_HOST
echo $DATASTORE_DATASET
```

Then in my Java Main Class I ran this:

```
public class Main{

    public main(){
        try{
            Datastore datastore = DatastoreHelper.getDatastoreFromEnv();
            System.out.println("Success DataStore Initialize");

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println("Error initalizing: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    };
```

The catch runs and I get the following output:

```
INFO: Using no credential.
Dec 06, 2015 5:41:36 PM com.google.api.services.datastore.client.BaseDatastoreFactory makeClient
WARNING: Not using any credentials
datastore dataset not set in options
```

So it looks like a dataset and or credentials are not set, but the doc does not say anything bout this. I haven't signed up with Google cloud or anything yet (not sue if I have to?) . I am first just trying to set it up locally and and run some basic 'Hello World' type of apps to get a feel for the database. If someone could please let me know what I am doing wrong that would be greatly appreciated! Cheers

PS: I will not be using Google App Engine. In the future I will run this directly from a Netty Java server which will call the database from there. As of right now though all of this is running locally on my machine.

Comment: The log entries relating to credentials are expected (credentials are not required to talk to the gcd tool). The part about "dataset not set" is not expected. Are you exporting the variables in the same shell that you're running Java in?

Comment: This is the reason! Thanks so much, I have added the variables to my startup scripts and all works now!

Comment: Please post this resolution as an answer and accept it, so the question can be properly seen as resolved, per SO etiquette -- thanks!